# Running Git-2.38.0-64-bit.exe gives "This program requires Windows service pack 1 or later"

Tags: windows, git, git-for-windows

I am trying to install Git-2.38.0-64-bit.exe on my Windows 10 Laptop. It immediately shows the error message "This program requires Windows service pack 1 or later."
I am running Windows 10  v. 21H1 Build 19043.2130. I am running Windows updates all the time, so this should be a quite current version. And I thought service packs were a thing of Windows 7.

So what should I do to be able to install that Git?

Comment: I am running 21H2 build 19044.2130 (so one major version ahead of you) and just updated to git version 2.38.0.windows.1 successfully. I would find it surprising, however, that Git should require such a recent version of Windows, it normally works on just about any version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows 10 is [officially supported by Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ#which-versions-of-windows-are-supported)

Try and:

- uncompress the [portable archive `PortableGit-2.38.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.38.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.38.0-64-bit.7z.exe) in C:\Git
- set a simplified path in a CMD:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "GH=C:\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

Check that Git is working in that CMD session, starting with `git version`.

Comment: I'm quite sure you meant GH=C:\Git.  WIth that, I can have git on my system. No installation needed, it seems. Only unpack.

Comment: @Dumuzy Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly. I have always prefered (in an enterprise setting) the portable option.